# Help with \bar accent

Tags: amsmath, accents, bar

I'm using the notation of conjugated complex numbers, however,  $\bar$ accent doesn't work well when summoning $\dfrac$ . What shall I do? [image]

```
$\dfrac{\bar{w}}{w} \cdot \bar{\dfrac{\bar{w}}{w}}$
```

Comment: I believe it's another instance of the annoying long-standing bug in nested accents. On the other hand, as a reader I'd be quite puzzled by something like `\bar{\dfrac{\bar{w}}{w}}`

Comment: Consider the use of `\overline` in the outer case, as in `\overline{\left(\dfrac{\bar{w}}{w}\right)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unfortunately a long-standing bug with nested accents in `amsmath`.

Here's a workaround, but the result is not that pretty, isn't it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\fixaccent@box}
\newcommand{\fixaccent}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\fixaccent@{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\fixaccent@}[2]{\fixaccent@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\fixaccent@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox{\fixaccent@box}{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  #2{\usebox{\fixaccent@box}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\bar{w}}{w}\cdot\fixaccent\bar{\frac{\bar{w}}{w}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

No reader will understand what the top bar refers to. Probably something like

[image]

obtained by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\bar{w}}{w}\cdot\,\overline{\!\Bigl(\frac{\bar{w}}{w}\Bigr)\!}\,
\]

\end{document}
```

could more clearly convey the idea. But probably

[image]

would be better.